# Is it bad to use a Linux username that is the same as a Linux command?

Tags: linux, user-accounts

Let's say your name is Ed. Would it be bad to make your username "ed" if it coincides with the line-oriented text editor by the same name, `ed`?

https://linux.die.net/man/1/ed

Comment: Related: Even some highly privileged software can and occasionally does default to [dangerous](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2020-13776) handling of usernames in input where it is incorrectly assumed that the intersection of different types of input was empty.

Answer (score 2):

In general, it is a fairly common practice on significant pieces of software, so its OK. It has the advantage if making it easier/obvious to tie software and usernames together.  (Examples off the top of my head include apache / https / mysql  / postgres / postfix - although in Ubuntu type distros the apache user is changed to www-data)

Where it might be less then ideal in the case you posit - where the username bears no relation to the programming. While there is no reason this won't work, and there is not a compelling case against it, it has the potential to create confusion for system administrators, particularly where they might write crude scripts with ps and grep and may have unintended consequences - of-course, these scripts are the problem, not the username.

Answer (score 1):

It should be fine.  If you find an issue, consider it a bug and report it as such (that should be very unusual though; they are different namespaces).

Answer (score 1):

My name is Ed. This isn't an issue, but I don't use "ed" as a login name either.

I did had a developer whose initials were "rpm", though.

The systems we supported were initially commercial Unix (AIX, HP-UX, SCO).
When we migrated to Red Hat in 2002/2003, having the "rpm" user name caused all sorts of unexpected issues, prompting an eventual move to a different naming scheme.